# MySQL: Determine Table's Primary Key Dynamically

Tags: php, sql, mysql, primary-key

I'm, generating a SQL query like this in PHP:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s = %s WHERE %s = %s", ...);
```

Since almost every part of this query is dynamic I need a way to determine the table's primary key dynamically, so that I'd have a query like this:

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE %s SET %s=%s WHERE PRIMARY_KEY = %s", ...);
```

Is there a MySQL keyword for a table's primary key, or a way to get it?

I've used the information_schema DB before to find information like this, but it'd be nice if I didn't have to resort to that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
SHOW INDEX FROM <tablename>
```

You want the row where Key_name = PRIMARY

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html

You'll probably want to cache the results -- it takes a while to run SHOW statements on all the tables you might need to work with.

Comment: Thanks, that is great. I ended up using this:

SHOW KEYS FROM <tablename> WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'

Comment: This returns the full row... if you want just the column name, see Jake Sully's answer below.

Comment: As the guy who wrote this answer, I have to agree: Jake Sully's answer is the best one so far.  @macinjosh I'd recommend un-accepting my answer, and accepting Jake's instead.

Answer (score 20):

It might be not advised but works just fine:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM <table_name> WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

The solid way is to use information_schema:

```
SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
    AND t.table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND t.table_name='owalog';
```

As presented on the [mysql-list](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/204944). However its a few times slower from the first solution.

Comment: Hi, I know this is an old post but I just wanted to ask why you said the first method is not advised. The accepted answer from [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341278/php-get-primary-key-of-table) says you don't always have access to the information_schema so it suggests the first method. Plus you said yourself that the second method is a few times slower than the first solution. If that is the case, why is the second method solid? Thanks.

Comment: As pointed in http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/05/better-way-to-get-primary-key-columns.html it can not be used as mysql variable or think view etc but if the first case works in your scenario go for it @Andrew

Answer (score 18):

A better way to get Primary Key columns:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'dbName')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'tableName')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

From http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/05/better-way-to-get-primary-key-columns.html

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
SHOW INDEX FROM <table_name> WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

Is equivalent to

```
SHOW KEYS FROM <table_name> WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on @jake-sully and @lukmdo answers, making a merge of their code, I finished with the following snippet:

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = DATABASE())
AND (`TABLE_NAME` = '<tablename>')
AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

Hope it could help someone