# How to get primary key of table?

Tags: php, mysql, primary-key

Is there a way to get the name of primary key field from mysql-database? For example:

I have a table like this:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo1 |
| 2 | Foo2 |
| 3 | Foo3 |

Where the field id is primary key (it has auto increment but I can't use that). How can I retrieve fields name "id" in php?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

A better way is to use `SHOW KEYS` since you don't always have access to information_schema. The following works:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Column_name will contain the name of the primary key.

Comment: Good suggestion. information_schema is supported as of MySQL 5.0, but indeed this method works for even older versions too.

Comment: Is there a way to only retrieve the `column_name` key?

Comment: use `cut` if you want to get just the column name: ` | cut -f5`

Comment: Any possible drawback from this approach over information.schema? It's for a plugin that will run on all kinds of SQL servers, MySQL/MariaDb, etc

Comment: @alexn is there a way to show primary keys of all tables with one command?

Comment: "Better" is arguable. Compatibility could be considered an important requirement just as well.

Answer (score 41):

Here is the Primary key Column Name

```
SELECT k.column_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
  AND t.table_schema='YourDatabase'
  AND t.table_name='YourTable';
```

Comment: yes - this is one way. In the MySQL case, you can even simplify this, because the constraint_name will always be `PRIMARY`

Comment: wouldnt recommend this at all it's very resource requiring
alexn's answer is far faster

Comment: yeah, this query takes long time. what i did is another table with table names and table ids and trying to fetch from there, if it can't find the table, so it makes this long query and add it to the new table, works much faster. but alexn answer seems to be really good too

Comment: But this solution works great when dealing with multiple tables.  (Just select k.table_name, k.column_name, k.ordinal_position).

Answer (score 24):

```sql
SELECT kcu.column_name, kcu.ordinal_position
FROM   information_schema.table_constraints tc
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
ON     tc.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = kcu.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG
AND    tc.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = kcu.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
AND    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  tc.table_schema = schema()             -- only look in the current schema
AND    tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND    tc.table_name = '<your-table-name>'    -- specify your table.
ORDER BY kcu.ordinal_position
```

Comment: Just an FYI, on **sqlserver**, `constraint_name` looks like `UK_entity_name`, `PK_Users`, `FK_Users_Contacts` etc., so it doesn't seem it can be trusted to have a well known platform-agnostic value. 

Comment: Whoa! I didn't expect you to update it.  Other than a few things, it works perfectly! (I updated your answer for you with the fixes, hope you don't mind)

Comment: @Christian thanks fort the quick follow up and correction. much obliged!

Comment: for me this was not working on an older mysql 5.5, changed to this one 
`SELECT kcu.column_name, kcu.ordinal_position
FROM   information_schema.table_constraints tc
INNER JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu
ON     tc.TABLE_SCHEMA = kcu.TABLE_SCHEMA 
AND    tc.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME 
AND    tc.CONSTRAINT_NAME = kcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
WHERE  tc.table_schema = schema()             -- only look in the current schema
AND    tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
AND    tc.table_name = 'logins'    -- specify your table.
ORDER BY kcu.ordinal_position`

Comment: Need to add `AND    tc.TABLE_NAME = kcu.TABLE_NAME` above `WHERE`

Answer (score 11):

use:

```
show columns from tablename where `Key` = "PRI";
```

Comment: This works best for me since I don't have to access the Information Schema (which is not available) and I can dynamically pick up the keys from the field column.

Answer (score 10):

How about this:

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Your Database'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Your Table name'
  AND COLUMN_KEY = 'PRI';


SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'Your Database'
  AND TABLE_NAME = 'Your Table name'
  AND COLUMN_KEY = 'UNI';
```

Comment: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'db' in 'where clause'

Comment: @zloctb: What about renaming `db` by your TABLE_SCHEMA...? I don't understand why you got +1 on this...

Comment: This was the clearest of the answers and worked immediately for me.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to generate the list of primary keys dynamically via PHP in one go without having to run through each table you can use

```sql
SELECT TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage 
WHERE table_schema = '$database_name' AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY'
```

though you do need to have access to the information.schema to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Shortest possible code seems to be something like

```
// $dblink contain database login details 
// $tblName the current table name 
$r = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($dblink, "SHOW KEYS FROM $tblName WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'")); 
$iColName = $r['Column_name'];
```

Answer (score 2):

For a PHP approach, you can use [mysql_field_flags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-field-flags.php)

```
$q = mysql_query('select * from table limit 1');

for($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields(); $i++)
    if(strpos(mysql_field_tags($q, $i), 'primary_key') !== false)
        echo mysql_field_name($q, $i)." is a primary key\n";
```

Comment: yup, good suggestion. although limited, this is a good enough for the primaruy keys.

Comment: The asker did say PHP.

Comment: This approch it's based on data and not on structure. So this approch will not work if the table has zero records.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it, finally!

```php
<?php

function mysql_get_prim_key($table){
    $sql = "SHOW INDEX FROM $table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'";
    $gp = mysql_query($sql);
    $cgp = mysql_num_rows($gp);

    if ($cgp > 0) {
        // Note I'm not using a while loop because I never use more than one prim key column
        $agp = mysql_fetch_array($gp);
        extract($agp);
        
        return($Column_name);
    } else {
        return(false);
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use SHOW INDEX FROM table ; it gives me alot of informations ; if the key is unique, its sequenece in the index, the collation, sub part, if null, its type and comment if exists, see screenshot here[image: here]

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL has a SQL query "SHOW INDEX FROM" which returns the indexes from a table.
For eg. - the following query will show all the indexes for the products table:-

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM products \G
```

It returns a table with type, column_name, Key_name, etc. and displays output with all indexes and primary keys as -

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
        Table: products
   Non_unique: 0
     Key_name: PRIMARY
 Seq_in_index: 1
  Column_name: product_id
    Collation: A
  Cardinality: 0
     Sub_part: NULL
       Packed: NULL
         Null: 
   Index_type: BTREE
      Comment: 
Index_comment:
```

To just display primary key from the table use :-

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM table_name WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation as to why this answers the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have spatial tables in your database, use:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM table WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY' OR Key_name = 'OGR_FID'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use PRIMARY from `key_column_usage.constraint_name = "PRIMARY"`

sample query,

```
SELECT k.column_name as PK, concat(tbl.TABLE_SCHEMA, '.`', tbl.TABLE_NAME, '`') as TABLE_NAME
FROM information_schema.TABLES tbl
JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k on k.table_name = tbl.table_name
WHERE k.constraint_name='PRIMARY'
  AND tbl.table_schema='MYDB'
  AND tbl.table_type="BASE TABLE";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT k.column_name
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage k   
WHERE k.table_name = 'YOUR TABLE NAME' AND k.constraint_name LIKE 'pk%'
```

I would recommend you to watch all the fields