# SQL query to obtain the columns that determine the primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, ssms

In SQL Server Management Studio, queries like this one:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS WHERE TABLE_NAME = [name_of_table];
```

can help find the name of the primary key, and I can easily find the name of the primary key in Object Explorer too, but I have yet to find way of identifying the table columns that uniquely determine the primary key. I have also consulted [this particular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341278/php-get-primary-key-of-table?noredirect=1&lq=1), but "SHOW ..." within a query is always recognized as invalid on my end. Furthermore, the other queries suggested by that post were able to extract the name of my primary key (which I already have a means of obtaining as described at the beginning of this question), but I still don't know where to find the underlying columns that determine the primary key. Any ideas?

Comment: Any query involving "SHOW KEYS" is not recognized as valid within my version of SSMS. I typically use INFORMATION_SCHEMA to find out meta information about tables

Comment: For SSMS, [this would appear to be a better duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table).