# How to get TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT along with CONSTRAINT_NAME: INFORMATION_SCHEMA in mySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, sys, information-schema

I just need to get the columns which has Primary Key, Foreign Key along with TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html , if so what difficulty are you having? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I see all foreign keys to a table or column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201621/how-do-i-see-all-foreign-keys-to-a-table-or-column) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341278/how-to-get-primary-key-of-table