# SQL query to find Primary Key of a table?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

How can I find which column is the *primary key* of a table by using a query?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @JoãoSilva - oracle, sql server, mysql.

Comment: You should definitely provide more detail in case of further questions, and use appropriate tags to add some context to the question. In this question, for example, the answer can be very different, depending on the specific database you are using.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/893874/mysql-determine-tables-primary-key-dynamically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you list the primary key of a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: This will get you the primary key in SQL Server `SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<YourTableName>' AND  SUBSTRING(CONSTRAINT_NAME,1,2)='PK'`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For Oracle, you can look it up in the [`ALL_CONSTRAINTS`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1044.htm) table:

```
SELECT a.COLUMN_NAME
FROM all_cons_columns a INNER JOIN all_constraints c 
     ON a.constraint_name = c.constraint_name 
WHERE c.table_name = 'TBL'
  AND c.constraint_type = 'P';
```

**[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/4409f/4)**.

For SQL Server, it was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3942921/140816), and for MySQL check [@ajon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12379241/440294).

Answer (score 28):

This is a duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893874/mysql-determine-tables-primary-key-dynamically):

credit to Lukmdo for this answer:

It might be not advised but works just fine:

```
show index from TABLE where Key_name = 'PRIMARY' ;
```

The solid way is to use information_schema:

```
SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
    AND t.table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND t.table_name='owalog';
```

Comment: Why do you assume it's MySQL?

Comment: True, this applies at least to MySQL

Answer (score 11):

For MySQL:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME), TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  TABLE_SCHEMA = '**database name**'
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME='PRIMARY'
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;
```

**Warning** a primary key with two columns will have them separated by a coma (`,`)

Comment: That gives me this error: `'GROUP_CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.`

Answer (score 7):

Try this query in  SQL server:

```
SELECT     X.NAME AS INDEXNAME,
           COL_NAME(IC.OBJECT_ID,IC.COLUMN_ID) AS COLUMNNAME
FROM       SYS.INDEXES  X 
INNER JOIN SYS.INDEX_COLUMNS  IC 
        ON X.OBJECT_ID = IC.OBJECT_ID
       AND X.INDEX_ID = IC.INDEX_ID
WHERE      X.IS_PRIMARY_KEY = 1
  AND      OBJECT_NAME(IC.OBJECT_ID)='YOUR_TABLE'
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query gives the list of all the primary keys in the given database.

```
SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME ,column_name
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA IN ('*your_db_name*');
```

Comment: Not strictly true, it will return all unique keys, not only primaries

Answer (score 3):

In mySQL

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM `table_name`;
```

This show the details of the columns ie field, data-type, key etc.

Comment: That gives me this error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.`

Answer (score 1):

It's more easy way to do it:

```
DESC TABLE;
```

It shows you the structure of your TABLE;

Answer (score 0):

LEFT joining table_constraints seems to take more time on mine.
i use `Information_schema.COLUMNS`

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME , COLUMN_NAME 
FROM Information_schema.Columns 
WHERE COLUMN_KEY = "PRI" AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
```

Comment: what was that about an EDIT you made ?

Answer (score 0):

This this on SSMS  -----

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.key_column_usage
WHERE TABLE_NAME='YOUR_TABLE'------
```

Answer (score 0):

For MS SQL Sever easy way to get the Primary key for the table

```
EXEC sp_pkeys TableName;

ex: EXEC sp_pkeys Users;
```

Comment: To get all keys use below query:
    SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Users';

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server

```
select Column_Name from information_schema.key_column_usage
where 
Constraint_Catalog='**DB_Name**' and
Constraint_Schema='**Schema Name**' and
Table_Name='**Table Name**' and
constraint_name like 'PK%'
```

Answer (score -1):

**For MSSQL:**
SELECT DISTINCT C.TABLE_NAME,C.COLUMN_NAME,C.DATA_TYPE
FROM sys.indexes I
INNER JOIN sys.index_columns IC ON I.OBJECT_ID = IC.OBJECT_ID AND I.INDEX_ID = IC.INDEX_ID
INNER JOIN information_schema.columns C ON COL_NAME(IC.OBJECT_ID,IC.COLUMN_ID) = C.COLUMN_NAME
WHERE I.IS_PRIMARY_KEY = 1