# MySQL - How to get primary key of a table?

Tags: mysql, primary-key, information-schema

Can anyone please tell me how to get the primary key of a table in MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930338/sql-server-get-table-primary-key-using-sql-query

Comment: Which Server MySQL, SQL Server....?

Comment: This is a duplicate. Please use the search function next time. -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you list the primary key of a SQL Server table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95967/how-do-you-list-the-primary-key-of-a-sql-server-table)

Comment: @DineshDB MySQL

Comment: @MBijen I want to get PKey from a table (MySQL)

Comment: See the answer from @DineshDB or you could use: `show index from TableName where Key_name = 'PRIMARY' ;`

Comment: Try SHOW INDEXES FROM tablename WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'

Comment: @MBijen the above query isn't working. Error - "FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 mismatched input 'from' expecting ON near 'index' in show statement"

Comment: @user3040610 Tried- Not working

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi Sorry it should be indexes instead of index. `SHOW INDEXES FROM TableName WHERE Key_name = "PRIMARY";`

Comment: @MBijen not working...

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi - I have tested it .it is working for me and it should work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get primary key of table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2341278/get-primary-key-of-table)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

**Solution 1:**

This is from [Ajons Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12379241/3876565)

```
SELECT k.COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.table_constraints t
LEFT JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage k
USING(constraint_name,table_schema,table_name)
WHERE t.constraint_type='PRIMARY KEY'
    AND t.table_schema=DATABASE()
    AND t.table_name='owalog';
```

**Solution 2:**

This is from [alexn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2341388/3876565)

```
SHOW KEYS FROM tablename WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

**Solution 3:**

```
SHOW INDEX FROM presort.final_conf_score_mld_run2 
WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY';
```

Comment: None of them is working....Can you just help me with the query - if my table name is "final_conf_score_mld_run2" and database name is "presort", what should be the query according to solution 1?

Comment: Also if we can view the schema of the table - it will show which column is PRIMARY KEY. How to view the schema?

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi, Try the third one.

Comment: Solution 3 also not working.... Error - "FAILED: ParseException line 1:11 mismatched input 'FROM' expecting ON near 'INDEX' in show statement"

Comment: @AnubhavSarangi Are you sure you are using mysql? Since all of them should work.

Comment: Sorry @MBijen @DineshDB - the solution 3 worked.... slight change in query - SHOW INDEX FROM presort.final_conf_score_mld_run2 
WHERE `Key_name` = 'PRIMARY';