# Get MySQL primary key and foreign keys constraints from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm building a datagrid application integrated with Smarty, using PDO/PHP/MySQL.

Is there a fast and convenient way (using db schema or some PDO command) to obtain in PHP:

- a table's primary key
- a table's foreign key constraints list?

(I'm using InnoDB as schema).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get key information by querying the `information_schema` table:

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'my_table_name'
```

[MySQL: How to I find all tables that have foreign keys that reference particular table.column AND have values for those foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806989/mysql-how-to-i-find-all-tables-that-have-foreign-keys-that-reference-particular)

You can get the primary key by using `SHOW TABLE`:

```
SHOW INDEX FROM my_table_name 
WHERE key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

[MySQL: Determine Table's Primary Key Dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893874/mysql-determine-tables-primary-key-dynamically)

Quering the `information_schema` table can be slow on server with lots of databases/tables.

You can use this to speed it up:

```
SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0
```

http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2011/12/23/solving-information_schema-slowness/

Comment: Thanks a lot, expecially for the information_schema performance tip, it's precisely the kind of information I needed.