# Getting foreign key constraints from a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have a MySQL table with foreign key constraints, eg.

```
CREATE TABLE `yiingles_version` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `package_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `version` varchar(64) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `distUrl` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `package_id` (`package_id`),

  CONSTRAINT `yiingles_version_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`package_id`) REFERENCES `yiingles_package` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

How can I get programmatically the values for `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE`, in this case **`CASCADE`**?

I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813168/get-mysql-primary-key-and-foreign-keys-constraints-from-php) and also took a look at MySQL's `information_schema` database, but did not find a way to get the values mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the `information_schema.referential_constraints` table.  Specifically, the `UPDATE_RULE` and `DELETE_RULE` columns.